# Carriage return that works in both HTML and in text

Tags: html, sql, sql-server-2008, email, text

I am working on some code that dumps data into a table.

Some of the data includes carriage returns.

Eventually, the data will be exported as an HTML-formatted email or in a text file (CSV), or both.  I don't know in advance which export method will be used on this data.

If I write my carriage returns to the database like this:

```
UPDATE SOME_TABLE
SET TEXT_VALUE = @LineOne + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + @LineTwo
WHERE ID = @IDValue
```

Then it works in the CSV file just fine, but the HTML email gets totally screwed up - it confuses the encoding and displays the email with header and mime information and is totally useless except for debugging.

On the other hand, if I write my carriage returns to the database like this:

```
UPDATE SOME_TABLE
SET TEXT_VALUE = @LineOne + '<br>' + @LineTwo
WHERE ID = @IDValue
```

Then it's the other way around - it works in email but the text file outputs with the actual "br" embedded in the text, as in "LineOne< br>LineTwo".

Is there a way to represent a carriage return in a way that will produce the same result in **both** plain text **and** in HTML?

All of this is running on SQL Server 2008 from inside a T-SQL stored procedure.

Comment: Can you put it inside a `<pre>` tag in the HTML? Also I don't see why the presence of a crlf in an HTML email should actually mess things up as opposed to having no effect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the most appropriate way is to store all text "as-is" with CR LF and then make the proper manipulations when you fetch the data from the table, ie. convert newlines to 
 if you are rendering html, etc.

Comment: Your solution is I think the right design.  The difficulty here is that I have no control over either the email or text processes - I am essentially feeding them data.

Answer (score 3):

This is one of those times that there is no easy answer to this.  HTML and plain text are interpreted very differently, as you are seeing here.  A newline is different in both, and not compatibile in the other.

What you need to do is to separate the logic into different stored procedures: one for HTML/email formatting, and one for plain text/csv formatting.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what language you are using to send the email. If it's PHP, you can use your normal text with carriage returns and transform them to html-linebreaks using:

```
nl2br($text);
```